# React native firebase - android not able to build

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification

For some reason I am unable to build my project. Yesterday everything worked fine, looking at https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_april_02_2019 there is a critical update from 5/11/21.

I tried to change the minSdkVersion as suggested but still no resolution.

This is the error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\Gilad\SaveLatestJoyRide-FE\joyride-fe\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
                              ^
  symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceId
  location: package com.google.firebase.iid
C:\Users\Gilad\SaveLatestJoyRide-FE\joyride-fe\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
                              ^
  symbol:   class InstanceIdResult
  location: package com.google.firebase.iid
C:\Users\Gilad\SaveLatestJoyRide-FE\joyride-fe\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java:143: error: cannot find symbol
              .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                                                            ^
  symbol:   class InstanceIdResult
  location: class RNPushNotification
C:\Users\Gilad\SaveLatestJoyRide-FE\joyride-fe\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java:145: error: cannot find symbol
                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                                                       ^
  symbol: class InstanceIdResult
C:\Users\Gilad\SaveLatestJoyRide-FE\joyride-fe\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java:142: error: cannot find symbol
      FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
      ^
  symbol:   variable FirebaseInstanceId
  location: class RNPushNotification
C:\Users\Gilad\SaveLatestJoyRide-FE\joyride-fe\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java:289: error: cannot find symbol
                  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
                  ^
  symbol: variable FirebaseInstanceId
Note: C:\Users\Gilad\SaveLatestJoyRide-FE\joyride-fe\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotificationHelper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Gilad\SaveLatestJoyRide-FE\joyride-fe\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\src\main\java\com\dieam\reactnativepushnotification\modules\RNPushNotification.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Please help! :(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I faced this issue recently, and resolving this is pretty easy. you would need to upgrade your native-push-notification. I suggest you change this in your package.json as so native-push-notification version to ^7.3.0. this worked for me. Iho[e this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I think there are some fixes they released in the last few days since they broke it. It works now, btw I am on ^7.3.1 :)

Comment: /Users/aps/ReactNativeApps/TickTalk/ticktalk/TickTalk/node_modules/react-native-tcp/android/src/main/java/com/peel/react/TcpSocketManager.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist

Answer (score 32):

just add the following under android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
    .....
    firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
}
```

Comment: Getting new error /Users/aps/ReactNativeApps/TickTalk/ticktalk/TickTalk/node_modules/react-native-tcp/android/src/main/java/com/peel/react/TcpSocketManager.java:3: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this issue by adding this line in my android gradle file.

> firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"

buildscript {
ext {
.....
firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
}